# Optimal Control Problem with nonlinear equations

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I am trying to minimize the vehicle's fuel consumption with safe constraints by using optimal control. There is a safe distance constraint

```py
p.Equation(p.s - p.sLead + p.dmin + p.v * 0.5 <= 0)
```

and a moving constraint for distance

```py
p.Equation(goal - p.final * p.s <= 0)
```

When I add the two constraints at the same time, the result shows

```
EXIT: Converged to a point of local infeasibility. Problem may be infeasible.

 An error occured.
 The error code is  2
```

When I remove the moving constraint for distance, the result seems meaningless, all the variables equal to the initial value. I am stuck with how to express the two constraints correctly in Gekko, please help me to check, the problem may find the local minimal successful solution?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

# Parameters
M, Av, Cd, rho, mu, g = 1200, 2.5, 0.32, 1.184, 0.013, 9.81
b0, b1, b2, b3 = 0.1569, 2.4508 * 10e-2, -7.415 * 10e-4, 5.975 * 10e-5
c0, c1, c2 = 0.07224, 9.681 * 10e-2, 1.075 * 10e-3

tf = 20
time = np.linspace(0, tf - 1, tf)

Ts = 1  # sample time
# Initial conditions of the lead car
v0Lead = 10  # m/s
s0Lead = 40  # m
vLead = v0Lead - 3.2 * np.sin(0.3 * time) + 0.2 * np.random.rand(len(time))
sLead = np.zeros(len(time))
sLead[0] = s0Lead
for i in range(1, len(time)):
    sLead[i] = sLead[i - 1] + Ts * vLead[i]

uMin, uMax, vMin, vMax = -2, 3, 0, 18
# Final goal to cross the red lights
goal0 = 200
# Practical gap
goalGap = 5
goal = goal0 + goalGap

dMin = 5

v0 = 5
s0 = 5
u0 = (0.5 / M) * Cd * rho * Av * (v0 ** 2) + mu * g

uHost = np.ones(tf) * u0
uHost[-1] = 0
vHost = np.ones(tf) * v0
sHost = s0 + vHost * np.linspace(0, tf - 1, tf)


def modelopt(dMin, v0, s0, t_cons):
    # MODEL
    p = GEKKO(remote=False)
    # parametre
    p.time = time
    '''
    final = np.zeros(tf)
    index = int(t_cons - 1)
    final[index] = 1
    p.final = p.Param(value=final)
    '''
    p.dmin = p.Param(value=dMin, name='dmin')
    p.u = p.MV(value=u0, lb=uMin, ub=uMax, name='Tractive Force')
    p.u.STATUS = 1
    p.u.DCOST = 0  # Delta cost penalty for MV movement
    p.u.DMAX = 20

    p.sLead = p.FV(value=sLead, name="preceding distance")

    p.a = p.CV(name="acceleration")
    p.v = p.CV(value=v0, lb=vMin, ub=vMax, name="velocity")
    p.s = p.SV(value=s0, name="distance")
    #p.s.STATUS = 1

    # S_final = p.s.value[-1]

    p.obj = p.Var(name="objective")

    p.Equation(p.s.dt() == p.v)
    p.Equation(p.v.dt() == p.a)
    p.Equation(p.a == (-1 / (2 * M)) * Cd * rho * Av * p.v ** 2 - mu * g + p.u)

    # p.Equation(goal - p.final * p.s <= 0)
    p.Equation(p.s - p.sLead + p.dmin + p.v * 0.5 <= 0)

    p.Equation(p.obj == p.if2(p.a, (b0 + b1 * p.v + b2 * (p.v ** 2) + b3 * (p.v ** 3)) / p.v,
                              (b0 + b1 * p.v + b2 * (p.v ** 2) + b3 * (p.v ** 3) +
                               p.a * (c0 + c1 * p.v + c2 * (p.v ** 2))) / p.v))

    p.Minimize(p.sum([p.obj]))

    p.options.IMODE = 6

    try:
        p.solve(disp=True)
    except:
        print('Not successful')
        p.open_folder()
        from gekko.apm import get_file
        print(p.server)
        print(p.model_name)
        f = get_file(p.server, p.model_name, 'infeasibilities.txt')
        f = f.decode().replace('\r', '')
        with open('infeasibilities.txt', 'w') as fl:
            fl.write(str(f))

    uHost = p.u.value[1]
    vHost = p.v.value[1]
    sHost = p.s.value[1]
    return uHost, vHost, sHost


vHost = np.ones(tf) * v0
sHost = s0 + vHost * time

uControl = np.zeros(tf - 1)
vControl = np.zeros(tf)
vControl[0] = v0
sControl = np.zeros(tf)
sControl[0] = sHost[0]
goal_cons = np.zeros(tf)
t_cons = np.zeros(tf)
goal_cons[0] = goal
t_cons[0] = tf
for t in range(tf - 1):
    uControl[t], vControl[t + 1], sControl[t + 1] = modelopt(dMin, vControl[t], sHost, t_cons[t])
    sHost = sControl[t + 1] + vControl[t + 1] * np.linspace(0, tf - 1, tf)
    goal_cons[t + 1] = goal - sControl[t + 1]
    t_cons[t + 1] = t_cons[t] - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the equation `p.Equation(goal - p.final * p.s <= 0)` is that when `p.final` is zero (everywhere except the final point) then the equation reduces to `p.Equation(goal <= 0)`. This creates an infeasible constraint if `goal>0`. The correct way to reformulate the problem is:

```py
p.Equation((goal - p.s)*p.final <= 0)
```

so that the equation is `0<=0` everywhere that `p.final=0`. When `p.final=1` then the equation becomes `goal <= p.s`. If `goal` is negative then switch the sign. An equality constraint can also be used but an inequality is generally easier to solve if it is okay to exceed the goal or there is a range for the goal with an upper and lower bound.

A couple other tips:

- Use `if3` instead of `if2` if the mixed integer solution doesn't take too long to solve.
- The objective function is only one variable so `p.Minimize(p.sum([p.obj]))` can be replaced by `p.Minimize(p.obj)`.

Here is the complete code:

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

# Parameters
M, Av, Cd, rho, mu, g = 1200, 2.5, 0.32, 1.184, 0.013, 9.81
b0, b1, b2, b3 = 0.1569, 2.4508 * 10e-2, -7.415 * 10e-4, 5.975 * 10e-5
c0, c1, c2 = 0.07224, 9.681 * 10e-2, 1.075 * 10e-3

tf = 20
time = np.linspace(0, tf - 1, tf)

Ts = 1  # sample time
# Initial conditions of the lead car
v0Lead = 10  # m/s
s0Lead = 40  # m
vLead = v0Lead - 3.2 * np.sin(0.3 * time) + 0.2 * np.random.rand(len(time))
sLead = np.zeros(len(time))
sLead[0] = s0Lead
for i in range(1, len(time)):
    sLead[i] = sLead[i - 1] + Ts * vLead[i]

uMin, uMax, vMin, vMax = -2, 3, 0, 18
# Final goal to cross the red lights
goal0 = 200
# Practical gap
goalGap = 5
goal = goal0 + goalGap

dMin = 5

v0 = 5
s0 = 5
u0 = (0.5 / M) * Cd * rho * Av * (v0 ** 2) + mu * g

uHost = np.ones(tf) * u0
uHost[-1] = 0
vHost = np.ones(tf) * v0
sHost = s0 + vHost * np.linspace(0, tf - 1, tf)


def modelopt(dMin, v0, s0, t_cons):
    # MODEL
    p = GEKKO(remote=False)
    # parametre
    p.time = time

    final = np.zeros(tf)
    index = int(t_cons - 1)
    final[index] = 1
    p.final = p.Param(value=final)

    p.dmin = p.Param(value=dMin, name='dmin')
    p.u = p.MV(value=u0, lb=uMin, ub=uMax, name='Tractive Force')
    p.u.STATUS = 1
    p.u.DCOST = 0  # Delta cost penalty for MV movement
    p.u.DMAX = 20

    p.sLead = p.FV(value=sLead, name="preceding distance")

    p.a = p.CV(name="acceleration")
    p.v = p.CV(value=v0, lb=vMin, ub=vMax, name="velocity")
    p.s = p.SV(value=s0, name="distance")

    p.obj = p.Var(name="objective")

    p.Equation(p.s.dt() == p.v)
    p.Equation(p.v.dt() == p.a)
    p.Equation(p.a == (-1 / (2 * M)) * Cd * rho * Av * p.v ** 2 - mu * g + p.u)

    p.Equation((goal - p.s)*p.final <= 0)
    p.Equation(p.s - p.sLead + p.dmin + p.v * 0.5 <= 0)

    p.Equation(p.obj == p.if3(p.a, (b0 + b1 * p.v + b2 * (p.v ** 2) + b3 * (p.v ** 3)) / p.v,
                              (b0 + b1 * p.v + b2 * (p.v ** 2) + b3 * (p.v ** 3) +
                               p.a * (c0 + c1 * p.v + c2 * (p.v ** 2))) / p.v))

    p.Minimize(p.sum([p.obj]))

    p.options.IMODE = 6

    try:
        p.solve(disp=True)
    except:
        print('Not successful')
        p.open_folder()
        from gekko.apm import get_file
        print(p.server)
        print(p.model_name)
        f = get_file(p.server, p.model_name, 'infeasibilities.txt')
        f = f.decode().replace('\r', '')
        with open('infeasibilities.txt', 'w') as fl:
            fl.write(str(f))

    uHost = p.u.value[1]
    vHost = p.v.value[1]
    sHost = p.s.value[1]
    return uHost, vHost, sHost


vHost = np.ones(tf) * v0
sHost = s0 + vHost * time

uControl = np.zeros(tf - 1)
vControl = np.zeros(tf)
vControl[0] = v0
sControl = np.zeros(tf)
sControl[0] = sHost[0]
goal_cons = np.zeros(tf)
t_cons = np.zeros(tf)
goal_cons[0] = goal
t_cons[0] = tf
for t in range(tf - 1):
    uControl[t], vControl[t + 1], sControl[t + 1] = modelopt(dMin, vControl[t], sHost, t_cons[t])
    sHost = sControl[t + 1] + vControl[t + 1] * np.linspace(0, tf - 1, tf)
    goal_cons[t + 1] = goal - sControl[t + 1]
    t_cons[t + 1] = t_cons[t] - 1
```

Each subproblem solves in a little over 1 second.

```
 ----------------------------------------------
 Dynamic Control with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      1.09 NLPi:   36 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    3 Obj:  2.69E+01 Gap:       NaN
--Integer Solution:   2.69E+01 Lowest Leaf:   2.69E+01 Gap:   0.00E+00
Iter:     2 I:  0 Tm:      0.02 NLPi:    1 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    3 Obj:  2.69E+01 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  1.1361999999999999 sec
 Objective      :  26.93268710232714
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```